# Response contains struct value where string expected

Tags: c#, .net, xml-rpc

I have the C# code where I am using xmlrpc and i am getting the following error

```
"Response contains struct value where string expected (as type string) [response: array mapped to type string[]: element 0]
```

I am newbie to C# so not sure how to tackle this one.

here is where its doing xml call

[XmlRpcMethod("test.login")]
    string[] tfunc(string hash, string timestamp, string domain, string nonce, string sessid, string username, string password);

and here is where I am calling it from in my class program

```
string[] d = iss.tfunc(hash, domain, timestamp, nonce, "user", "user", "pass");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What types are `hash`, `domain`, `timestamp`, and `nouce` defined as?  Try adding `.ToString()` to any variables that aren't `String` types.

```
string[] d = iss.tfunc(
    hash.ToString(),
    domain.ToString(),
    timestamp.ToString(),
    nonce.ToString(),
    "user",
    "user",
    "pass");
```